# Reading data from response header of NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

How can I read the data from the header sent by in the server response. I am using NSURLConnection to send the request.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If the URL is an HTTP URL, then the `NSURLResponse` that you receive in your connection's delegate's `-connection:didReceiveResponse:` method (or via another method) will be an `NSHTTPURLResponse`, which has an [`-allHeaderFields`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpurlresponse/1417930-allheaderfields) method that lets you access the headers.

```
NSURLResponse* response = // the response, from somewhere
NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
// now query `headers` for the header you want
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case

```
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response]);
    NSDictionary *headers = [response allHeaderFields];
```

Good Approach

```
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)[task response];
    if ([httpResponse respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
         NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
         NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary description]);
    }
```