# Getting img tag response headers from UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with some static HTML.
I want to get the response headers for the img from that html.

code:

```
let html = "<html><body><img src=\"\(imageUrl)\" alt=\"test\" width=\"70\" height=\"70\"></body></html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

---

```
extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if let html = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML") {
        print("html: \(html)")

    }

    print("finish load")

    let res = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: webView.request!)
    print("res: \(res)")
    print("headers: \(res?.response)")
}
}
```

the cached response is always nil.

Is there a way to get the headers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

suggest to use NSURLConnection to make the request and extract the the headers field using NSURLResponse. can follow and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273094/reading-data-from-response-header-of-nsurlconnection)

Comment: This wont work for me.
I'm using a external service, and for it to work i need to call this url from a html.

Comment: have you tried this before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325818/get-uiwebview-response-header ?

Comment: yes, look at the code in my question... its exactly that.

Comment: you got anything for your HTML content?

Comment: Yes, I get the html I loaded

Comment: how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880416/get-http-response-header-on-uiwebview